# Programatically change exposed filter value based on another exposed filter

Tags: views

I have 2 exposed filters in my Drupal 8 view - both are select dropdowns. I want the value of the 2nd filter to change based on selection of first filter
Here are the filters
`$filters = $view->display_handler->getOption('filters');`

`$filters['country']` and `$filters['states']`.

Problem is that I always get an empty value when I try to access country filter in my views_pre_view hook.

`dpm($filters['country']['value'])` always prints empty.

How do I solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to your filter options inside `hook_views_pre_view`.

```
$filters = $view->display_handler->getOption('filters');
```

give only informations about the filter something like:

```
 "field_country_target_id" => array:20 [▼
    "id" => "field_country_target_id"
    "table" => "node__field_country"
    "field" => "field_country_target_id"
    "relationship" => "none"
    "group_type" => "group"
    "admin_label" => ""
    "operator" => "or"
    "value" => []
    "group" => 1
    "exposed" => true
    "expose" => array:13 [▶]
    "is_grouped" => false
    "group_info" => array:10 [▶]
    "reduce_duplicates" => false
    "type" => "select"
    "limit" => true
    "vid" => "countries"
    "hierarchy" => false
    "error_message" => true
    "plugin_id" => "taxonomy_index_tid"
  ]
```

To get the selected filter values with:

```
$filters_selected = $view->getExposedInput();
```

Even you get the filter options you can't alter it because exposed filters are form inputs.
So i thing the best way to achieve this is by using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` like the following.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MY_MODUOLE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Here is options of your country filter
  // Note that they key is FIELD_NAME_target_id
  // Change the FIELD_NAME with you field name
  $countries = $form['field_country_target_id']['#options'];
  // Get the city options the same way .
  /**
   * TODO: To alter options array change $form['field_country_target_id']['#options'] not the $countries
   */
}
```

Comment: Thanks berramou, but how does this help me get the currently value of the countries drop-down filter? I need the value of that filter not just all the options. It's the value of countries filter that will determine values I populate states filter with..

Comment: Also ```$form['field_country_target_id']['#options']``` doesn't work. What works for me is ```$form['country'] ['#options'] ``` and that returns the list of all countries rather than the selected option.

Comment: check my edit to get selected values try with `$view->getExposedInput()`

Comment: i just gave you an example with my field and i add the comment **Change the FIELD_NAME with you field name**  to change it with your field name

Comment: Thanks again berramou for quick reply. I tried the ```$view->getExposedInput()``` but got the following output from dpm

Comment: Thanks again berramou for quick reply. I tried the ```$view->getExposedInput()``` but got the following output from dpm
```Array
(
    [live_preview] => 1
    [_triggering_element_name] => op
    [_triggering_element_value] => Update preview
    [_wrapper_format] => drupal_ajax
)```

Comment: your view is ajaxify ? or you test in preview ?

Comment: Pls how do I get the exposed country filter value from that array?

Comment: try with `dpm($view->getExposedInput());` go to the view and select country and submit you will have the filter value